# Is it safe store sensible data in props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I am building a product using FLUX + ReactJS. I store the state of my component in Stores, but then, I need to move a lot of information (about logged user, or settings, etc..) in the components props for make them available to the component itself.

I was wondering if this it safe.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "safe"? are you taking from a security point of view? data integrity? performance?

Comment: Its Javascript, it doesn't natively run code on your server. If its read-only the data should be safe. If it makes it way back to the server then you should validate that the data is accurate.

Comment: @atmd I am talking about security. E.G. I have a parent component called App where I store the data of current logged in user for manipulating the interface

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that, having data in a property is not going to cause your data to be changed on your server unless you allow it.  Therefore if you feel the data is safe enough to display in a browser, than having react display that data is a non-issue.

Comment: Depending on your login in system you would likely have a cookie with an access token, or an access token elsewhere - each request that gives secure data back checks if the request has access

Comment: @ciaoben, from a security standpoint, it doesn't matter where the data is on the client, it just matters whether it's on the client or not. When asking security questions in the future, please mention specific attack vectors you're worried about.